# Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

Tags: c#, .net-core, iis, interop, word-interop

I'm using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` in .NET Core Application, it's working as expected in local but after hosted in IIS it's not working and I'm getting below error.

> **An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.**
> UnauthorizedAccessException: Retrieving the COM class factory for
> component with CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due
> to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (0x80070005
> (E_ACCESSDENIED)). System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType
> type, bool publicOnly, bool wrapExceptions, ref bool canBeCached, ref
> RuntimeMethodHandleInternal ctor, ref bool hasNoDefaultCtor)

If I Change IIS App Pool Identity to `LocalSystem` then getting below error.

> `An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.`
> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
> object.

and I tried  below Component Services => DCOMConfig properties are

1. Under General tab,  Authentication Level - connect.
2. Under security tab, select Customize in "Launch and Activation" section and Added IIS_IUsers with full permissions.

can anyone please suggest me how to resolve this ?

Comment: The classic server side Office automation that every new developers would like to bump into from time to time, but you really should take advice from the manufacturer https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2.

Comment: Besides, be mindful of the key differences as "it's working as expected in local" isn't enough in many other cases, https://halfblood.pro/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

Most server-side Automation tasks involve document creation or editing. Office 2007 supports new Open XML file formats that let developers create, edit, read, and transform file content on the server side.

instead of using the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word you could use the office open XML. here is the documentation you can refer :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb735940(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: You are right but I'm developing in project which is older and almost not possible to change code from all modules

Comment: @Ra_g could you try to set the app pool to the 32 bit enable and try again

Comment: The source document for this answer is https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2.  (The first two paragraphs are taken directly from it.)